# HTML5 audio won't show up using list.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have made a list using list.js, but I have an issue with the HTML5 audio tag.

I have this page: http://bagnummeret.dk/list and it works perfectly in desktop browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera). **But** if I visit the same page on my iPhone (Safari, Chrome, Opera), the audio won't show up.

The fix to make the audio show up is to is use 'id' on the `<ul>` instead of 'class': http://bagnummeret.dk/list-id

That'll make the audio show up in both desktop and mobile browsers. **However**, this breaks the list.js implementation, which filters on the class element. On the list-id page you can see that the filters won't work.

I'm not much of an expert into javascript and jquery, but a fix could be to go through the list.js code and make the filter work on 'id', but is that really necessary?

I hope I've supplied enough documentation for you to gain insight into my issue.

Comment: What happens if you code both classes *and* ids in the markup?

Comment: seems like mobile safari treats audio different, as read here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/index.html  not sure if that's your problem, but after a quick read through, seems like it's related

Comment: Thanks for the reference, albert. Seems like quite the task. It makes me wonder if I should try implementing the audio via javascript? But I'm sceptical since it's only difference between the id and the class elements that messes up the implementation.

Just FYI I've added the audio in mp3, ogg and aac format to accommodate the different mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed my issue using the [audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/) code :)